# Can’t submit answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

Since a few minutes ago, I haven’t been able to submit any answers on Stack Overflow:

[image: Screenshot of error]

This seems to happen on every question; I tried using both Firefox and Chromium. According to my profile page, I’m not blocked from answering. The question isn’t deleted, locked, or closed. I can comment fine. What’s going on?

… well, I assume it’s happening to everyone, since the last fifty or so questions have gone unanswered.

Comment: and the error in console is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Being fixed right now, show be good in a few minutes

Comment: Heh, shouldn't this be one of the first tests that gets checked before code is checked in? 1) PostQuestion() 2) PostAnswer()

Comment: And... fixed! On Stack Overflow at least.

Comment: Works! Works! I posted recently on SO.

Comment: @balpha [who is to blame?](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: I spinned and got: "It's The Server's fault!". No, really!

Comment: Gah, I thought it was just me not having enough rep to embed images, so converted them to links then though I hadn't the rep to post 6 links so I gave up..

Comment: Phew! Thanks to a `setInterval(_=>$('#submit-button').click(),30000)`, I still managed to get FGITW. =)

Comment: @bluefeet: [Nobody](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yD2sE.png)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

Who knew that being able to post a question doesn't guarantee being able to post an answer?

I will answer [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) posts and write some PHP as penance.

Comment: Answering discussion is fine... PHP is too much. We should save it for something **really bad**.

Comment: please not PHP!

Comment: Nice hat.  Where's your cat?