# About "Rep changes" and gaming system using them

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, reputation, gaming-the-system

Ever seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231808/what-does-rep-change-mean) post? Read it **carefully**, if you didn't. Mysticial's explanation is great.

To summarize the problem:

- You register, start with 1 rep.
- You posted an answer that was up voted 10 times, so you are now at 101 rep.
- You offer 100 rep bounty on some question.
- You are now at 1 rep (but you have 10 times up voted answer).
- You delete your +10 answer.
- But you still at 1 rep, system understand that you couldn't offer a bounty if you hadn't rep to offer it. So it gives you rep change and you rep is 1 now (otherwise it would be -99).
- Now you **undelete** your answer and have back 101 rep, as if you hadn't offer any bounty - you **get rep back for undeleted answer**, but **rep change is still there**, but it should be reversed so as you are back at 1 rep.

As you see, that is a small problem. If I'll undelete back my post, rep change that occurred doesn't get reversed. So this is feature-request before I get suspended (however it is a very important bug). Remove rep change events if post is undeleted.

Comment: So [that's what you've been doing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/231727/revisions).

Comment: @Bart you see, I said it.

Comment: Wow, this question is a bit popular!

Comment: But then we will  not be able to catch users who game the system.

Comment: @Sha My request prevents gaming the system. The thing is I delete post, get rep change, undelete it, **but** rep change isn't reversed, so I earn rep.

Comment: It can't be reversed because it means you'll have negative reputation. I think you are well aware of this and just trolling now. Not cool.

Comment: @Sha Oh. Then how did I earn rep? A? Edited.

Comment: @nicael I'm not 100% sure about this, but I'm sure you're exploiting a possible bug in the system to earn "free bounties".

Comment: @Sha Not really free. Especially 500 rep bounties. For 500 rep bounties I lose 50-100 reps. (if offer one). For 300-400 rep bounties I don't lose much rep and even gain it sometimes. For 50-150 rep bounties I gain rep 20-50 (**but** only when I have not much rep, otherwise I pay full bounty price, thats because I offer only 500 rep bounties last time - to minimize damage). And, btw, look at my rep tab in my account.

Comment: OK, so you are up to something. Point proven. You should really stop now and earn rep like everyone else.

Comment: @Sha but I anyway get suspended (will be really surprised if not, however I immediately undeleting all my good posts, ok?). And when I look at /reputation, do you know what I see at the bottom? `** rep from bonuses: 4609`. ))) Many bonuses had I earned, isn't it?

Comment: What can I say, you found the secret treasure.

Comment: @Sha I'll undelete all my good posts and we'll see my actual rep.

Comment: @nicael with all the bounties and mess with your deletes/undeletes really not sure it will be "actual rep". But go ahead, just please don't delete them again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I won't delete them any more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Deleted all negative-scored and undeleted all positive scored.

Comment: @Sha you see, how much rep I lose? I had 1,108 and now have 428. So bounties are not really free. And the second thing: if my bountied question doesn't get any response, I delete it when bounty expire.

Comment: @Sha now I will be up voted and your rep will be exactly 100 times bigger than mine ))

Comment: @nicael true. now that's cool.

Comment: +1 for finding a loophole, -1 for exploiting it, +1 for reporting it

Comment: @Sha I am back to my 1,243 rep! Even more than I have before!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks for the report, a fix for this will be rolling out to the network shortly. The users affected by this will be recalculated to reflect the loophole fix.

We were *adjusting* rep adjustments for bounty compensation as a matter of fixing historical data before rep was real-time. However, we did not remove them.

We now no longer blindly apply reputation adjustments chronologically in the rep calculation just before the bounty where they occur in history.  Instead, we now check the adjustment each time, make sure it matches what's already there, and update or insert the adjustment if it's not already correct.

Comment: May I check? ;)

Comment: You... I... Fixed, yeah?.. Uaaaaa!!!!!!! No. I'll break it again.

Comment: @nicael good luck :)

Comment: A hole.. certainly there is a hole... where is it?..

Comment: Do you know how many reps I earned from bonuses? `** rep from bonuses: 4217`. Hoho. Stack Exchange is generous. Wait. I just realized that I wasn't suspended.

Comment: So [this my post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231808/what-does-rep-change-mean) is historical now? No more "rep changes"? (Please don't delete it, simply close it or lock).

Comment: @nicael: sounds like it still applies, but now the calculation is more accurate.

Comment: Wait, stop! First bounty on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231498/stack-exchange-doesnt-allow-me-to-answer-protected-questions is real and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231060/increase-reputation-required-to-add-k-in-se-app are real bounties!!!

Comment: @nicael I have removed all bounties which you couldn't have chronologically given without this exploit as part of the global cleanup for you and the one other user (whom this looks to have inadvertently happened to).  The cleanup is now complete, you can issue any bounties with your current rep that you desire - no more cleanup to do.

Comment: You forgot to return a bounty on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231289/259214. Make it anonymous like others.

Comment: @nicael There's no bounty left on that question, did you mean to link to something else?

Comment: There *was* 350 rep bounty. In revisions of question I see only that I added notice without bounty. And, yes, I mean this question.

Comment: @nicael yes - which you weren't actually eligible to offer when it was offered, it was removed as part of the chronologically accurate cleanup.

Comment: No. Look at [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231060/increase-reputation-required-to-add-k-in-se-app#comment759712_231060). I had 371 reps and and only 21 left. It was the *real* bounty, my first bounty, I didn't know how to game bounties then.

Comment: And [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231808/what-does-rep-change-mean) was gamed bounty.

Comment: @nicael Due to rep changes that happened before then, you didn't have enough rep at the time it was offered - we have very detailed systems to track this. When the bounty was offered on May 8th at 6:56 PM UTC you had a running total of 343 reputation. [Here's a screenshot of your running totals](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uQfX3.png) You couldn't have legitimately offered that bounty until `2014-05-08 22:47:17Z` which the script realized when it removed it.

Comment: So there is something wrong with script. Ok, leave it as is. There may be a more serious problem.

Comment: That being said, I did forget to remove the notices in PostHistory as part of the cleanup - when you are done looking please ping me here and I'll run the removal. My objective it to cleanup, not inhibit your investigating that things are correct...we want them to be correct.

Comment: @nicael There is nothing wrong with the script that you have shown me here, unless I've missed something?  Bounties which you would not have enough rep to offer at the time they were offered were removed, that's exactly what it was designed to do - for all users.

Comment: [Look](http://stackexchange.com/users/3548243/nicael?tab=reputation) at my network graph. For Meta Stack Exchange  it is *right*. Look at May 7-8. What do you see?

Comment: @nicael Your network graph doesn't take into account private actions like downvotes or deleted content - it pretends as if they never existed to keep in line with historical behavior and keep your downvotes and such anonymous. If you are still concerned, then send me an email at craver at stackoverflow.com and I'll happily send you a complete historical record of every single rep change that ever happened.  You'll see it adds up perfectly and gives your total reputation at each moment in time.

Comment: @nicael if you want to see what I mean without waiting on me, simply go to your reputation tab in your profile and check/uncheck the box at the bottom "show removed posts" You'll see things like [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230634/accepting-question-without-any-comment) that caused a -6 but was deleted later (only yesterday) and eventually gave back rep...but *at that time*, it was a -6 on your total. Those items are the differences in what SE.com shows, it's the same public view of your reputation as on the site, excluding deleted content.

Comment: One more thing. Have you read this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231808/what-does-rep-change-mean)?

Comment: Wait, I didn't noticed something strange. [I earned "Edit posts" privilege???](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VdCDh.png). But it is false! I don't have it, I checked (and I can't have it of course because I need 2000 reps).

Comment: @nic you had over 2k at some point then it went down again. No bug this time. :)

Comment: @Sha But... I have the moment to game the system then!!!!! argghghghghghghgghgh!!!!! But how did I have more than 2000 reps? I didn't have more than 2000 reps there NEVER.

Comment: @nicael you did for a moment during the cleanup, this was already corrected but your persisted inbox is cached for a while, may take up to another hour to disappear.

Comment: But what if I bountied those rep during cleanup?..

Comment: @nicael This was a one-time closing of the first reputation loophole in over 18 months, I'd have just cleaned them up. A cleanup need not be fancy - it was quickly written to address the rep issues of 2 users, out of millions.

Comment: 2 users? Out of curiosity, who was the second?

Comment: Started a bounty to reward your answer. Got "306 rep change". So, it is kind of gaming the system again (by mistake ;) ), so you can invalidate all my bounties.

Comment: YES, I managed to game the system by 2 reps! Progress!

Comment: Nick, is it expected behavior that unwitting participants would lose their earned bounties? [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233451/my-reputation-graph-in-network-profile-is-wrong) of mine was a lot of work, and while it still says `+500` next to it, the reputation has disappeared. If it's by design, no worries. Just checking.

Comment: Yep, I found another way of gaming system by some reps. Will see how much is it efficient.

Comment: Gamed only by 41 reps. ;-)

Comment: Wait, I noticed that all posts where you removed bounties still have bounty indicator (below votes count, blue +150, +500, etc) that has no bounties bonded.

Comment: The way I recently found in random way someway is way too conspicuous. Anyway no way to avoid posting it because *someone* already noticed this way someway.

Comment: @mhlester I'll earn the rep and award the bounties back to you (Anyway it would be *really* good if Nick Craver ♦ will return you earned rep).

Comment: I have a problem. My 500 rep gamed bounties on SO are still valid. Remove them please. [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902572/using-signalr-with-redis-messagebus-failover-using-booksleeves-connectionutils). [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints). [Third](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305020/interpret-xmp-metadata-in-alassetrepresentation)

Answer (score 7):

I'd been giving this some thought, and came to the same conclusion you did: once your reputation exceeds the amount of the `rep change`, it should be reversed with a second, negative `rep change`

---

Furthermore, I think *undeletion* events should trigger a bump, to bring attention to the acts. You've been undeleting [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231054/can-t-submit-answers/231058#231058) every time you post a bounty, and I see this in my profile each time:

[image]

But *only* those who downvoted you see anything. A bump would bring a lot more accountability and exposure.

This has been requested here: [Bump a deleted answer when it's undeleted, not when it's edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192918/bump-a-deleted-answer-when-its-undeleted-not-when-its-edited)

---

Lastly, it seems like any `rep change` events might warrant an automatic moderator flag. These are supposed to be exceedingly rare, but I assume of the 5650 rep you've offered in bounties, about 80% of that was actually through this shady method. A moderator warning would probably have stopped you much sooner.

---

At least you're not using sock puppets like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=1) who's had *14* `user was removed` events in his 7 months on Stack Overflow

> [image]

Comment: @nicael It's not that person's fault or responsibility when you gave them ill-gained reputation, when they had no knowledge or participation in it. Which mhlester did not.

Comment: The only potential 'irony' here would be if mhlester was saying what he did here after being a willing recipient of your exploit-gained reputation. That's the only way your comment above makes any sense. *Except that's simply not true*.

Comment: The day I posted [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233657/248072) was the day I learned of the stack overflow sock puppets and the prevalence of the rep change hack here. My answer was valuable information and an actual diagnosis of where SE's math is wrong, bounty or not. When I figured out what you were doing, I flagged your accounts for moderator review.

Comment: @nicael I know full well what irony is, what the timeline of events related to *all of this* is, and who "this guy" is. Your attempts to play smart aleck here are not helping you.

Comment: @nicael, please keep in mind I've voted on your posts objectively both before and since. I upvoted your post here. And [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233694/rep-gain-indicator-is-empty-if-it-is-none-rep-gain-and-it-is-confusing). And yes, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233451/my-reputation-graph-in-network-profile-is-wrong). But feel free to continue [unupvoting and downvoting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B6HG7.png) my old posts if you think my flagging your account was inappropriate given what I'd learned from the information you made public.

Comment: I think it was plenty direct, with a sprinkling of humor in how I phrased it. Anyone clicking through knew I was talking about you. You called yourself out for the sock puppets when you posted that your graph was wrong ([this one again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233451/my-reputation-graph-in-network-profile-is-wrong)), whether intentional or not.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings! Ok, now I understand the humor )). Sorry again.