# Is 100+100+100+100 really 1000?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088905/buras?tab=bounties&sort=offered) user have offered bounties for 1,000 reps... Wait, 1,000 reps? 100+100+100+100=1000?
Could anyone explain me why is it shown 1,000, not 400?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that there were some number of bounties totaling a value of 600 that were revoked by mods.

Comment: @Servy Some of my [bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=bounties) were [revoked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them#comment770529_234347) by Nick Craver, but system counts totals properly.

Comment: They also offered a bounty [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551297/how-to-open-a-dat-file-ascii) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868723/boundary-fill-flood-fill-algorithm-to-construct-an-interactive-map-java), but these bounties are not listed in their "offered" list, and also not in the "earned" list of the member who get the bounties.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: interesting, lost bounties! At least their reputation graph records the bounty reputation being deducted. **But no addition event in the receiving user** is recorded.

Comment: Appears to involve sock puppet accounts. See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130527173946/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551297/how-to-open-a-dat-file-ascii) - 8 upvotes, lost without a trace, different user with the bounty.... most likely sock puppets that got merged and/or nuked, bounty was manually revoked after being awarded. Wonder how you find it, nicael? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: heh, I found the other post on wayback around the same time as you found yours. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard He recently [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369165/how-to-force-save-and-restrict-open) a question and I saw that he has too mach badges. I went to his profile, opened bounties and ... my calculator. Wow, reversal? Big reversal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I thought it was a different user at first too, but it is only a different profile picture and username, the userid is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ProgramFOX found two posts by that user that had bounties posted to them:

- [Boundary fill (flood fill) algorithm to construct an interactive map. Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868723/boundary-fill-flood-fill-algorithm-to-construct-an-interactive-map-java)
- [How to open a .dat file (ASCII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551297/how-to-open-a-dat-file-ascii)

Both these bounties are recorded as having been awarded to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178635/cheburashka). From the [reputation history of that user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2178635/cheburashka?tab=reputation) I see that there were some.. suspicious events that point to the user having been caught at voting fraud before (a few user removed and serial voting reversed events).

So, although these bounties were awarded to this account, they were later revoked, manually, by a moderator, most likely because the answers had been upvoted through sock-puppets to inflate their likelyhood of earning the bounty. You can see that the vote total has *significantly* dropped when you look at archived copies of the pages:

- 3 votes missing: http://web.archive.org/web/20130614225603/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868723/boundary-fill-flood-fill-algorithm-to-construct-an-interactive-map-java
- 7 votes missing: http://web.archive.org/web/20130527173946/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551297/how-to-open-a-dat-file-ascii

(don't mind the changed profile picture; the user account is the same as the userid in the URL matches)

The *bounty offered total* was never updated. An insignificant side-effect of a vote-fraud cleanup then.

Comment: Why did you remove links to web archive?..

Comment: @nicael: because my conclusion was incorrect. I misread the userid in the link, it was not a sock-puppet account.

Comment: @nicael: I put them back to illustrate the missing vote counts.

Comment: Heh, really long history...

Comment: [WTF?!?!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UpiQl.png) Day? 7 events? Thats [there](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2088905/buras?tab=reputation)

Comment: @nicael: the user history is seeing some more cleanup.. Reversals applied 33 minutes ago. The serial voting events is just a caching artifact; these have been merged into one event.

Comment: @nicael: by the looks of it the moderators are cleaning up another (set of) sock puppets now that you drew attention to the account.

Comment: Nice answer @MartijnPieters!