# Will I get some reputation which I never had if I delete a post which is severely downvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Suppose I am a person with reputation 1(since it can't go lower than 1).
Now I have posted a really stupid question which has earned almost 100 downvotes(just an example).

A downvote reduces the reputation by 2. That means 200 reputation points are deducted. I am at 1 and so it has no effect.

We all know that deleting a question with downvotes will give me back all my reputation points. So what happens if I delete that stupid question with 100 downvotes?

Will I get some reputation that I never really had? I mean 200 reputation points which I never really had?

Comment: Well, there was a loophole with bounties, you'll probably find [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them) interesting to read. However, there was never such a loophole with simple votes. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will I get some reputation that I never really had?

No.

The reputation system is smart enough to calculate this correctly - it will not award unearned reputation.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: There are checks to see if the reputation was earned before refunding any. If it was not earned, it will not be refunded. If it was partially earned, only that part will be refunded.

Comment: @Oded I was under the impression that after a delete there is a recalc. Isn't this the case?

Comment: @Sha it's the case, anyway... But the down votes are recorded without any reputation loss if you're on 1 rep.

Comment: @nicael so you think there's a "ReputationLost" column on the Votes table, and when deleting there's only a simple `Set Reputation=Reputation+ReputationLost` for each vote? Sounds too.... simple, to me.

Comment: @Sha I have no idea how it's implemented. I've deleted/undeleted the post not once, including while being at 1 rep. It's always recalculated. As for the empty votes, you should know this too, by looking at the reputation tab of downvoted new users (this would also require to upvote&unupvote the post in order the votes to show).

Comment: @nicael why I am not surprised to discover you have tried ?:P

Comment: @Spa I have no idea :P